# rails 4 gem 'mongoid_slug' unable to search by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, slug

I just installed the gem 'mongoid_slug', here is the model:

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Slug

  field :_id, type: String, slug_id_strategy: lambda {|id| id.start_with?('....')}

  field :name, type: String
  slug :name, 
  ...
end
```

In the controller I have a function call get_book that I call before edit, show etc
Of course it is not working, I also tried find_by_slug.
Error `Document not found` for class Book with attributes `{:id=>"try-new-book"}`.

Request info

Request parameters
`{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"startups", "id"=>"try-new-book"}`

```
def get_book
  @book = Book.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
```

Thank you

Comment: What if `Book.find(params[:id])`? I don't understand clearly what this slug do, but mongoid have `_id` not `id`. So, it probably will be `Book.find_by(_id: params[:id])` of `find_by_id`

Comment: The slug makes pretty url instead of having /books/009333 it is supposed to do /books/try-new-book

Comment: I tried with Book.find_by_id but I have the following error message:      NoMethodError at /books/try-new-book
undefined method `find_by_id' for Book:Class

Comment: [According to docs](https://github.com/digitalplaywright/mongoid-slug#usage) it should works just `Book.find params[:id]`

Comment: When I try: .find_by(_id: params[:id]) I have the following error:Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound at /books/try-new-book

Problem:
  Document not found for class Book with attributes {:_id=>"try-new-book"}.
Summary:
  When calling Book.find_by with a hash of attributes, all attributes provided must match a document in the database or this error will be raised.

Comment: Yes, it's wrong, i mistook `id` for real mongo id, rather than a slug.

Comment: The thing that I do not understand is that the params passed have: 
Request parameters 
{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"books", "id"=>"try-new-book"} and the url is http://localhost:3000/books/try-new-book

Comment: It have only `id`, no other params. It's OK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongoid\_slug Rails 4 update / destroy object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267755/mongoid-slug-rails-4-update-destroy-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to docs](https://github.com/digitalplaywright/mongoid-slug#usage) it should works just:

```
Book.find params[:id]
```

**Updated**

I answered the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24268613/724036). So in short: change `id.start_with?('....')` to something like `id =~ /^[[:alnum:]]+$/`

Comment: I know but it does not. I am trying to understand. From the rails console I have the following: irb(main):023:0> s
=> #<Startup _id: 539ba0fe681191f2221a2110, created_at: 2014-06-14 01:10:22 UTC, updated_at: 2014-06-14 01:10:22 UTC, user_id: BSON::ObjectId('536fa6b36169721158000000'), company_name: "try new book", _slugs: ["try-new-book"]>

Comment: The id ~= \^[A-z\d]+$\ is not working unfortunately. I have this error: syntax error, unexpected '='
...ug_id_strategy: -> (id) { id ~= \^[[:alnum:]]+$\ }

Comment: Yes, sorry, i should be `id =~ /^[[:alnum:]]+$/ `

Comment: Ha, just find out that it's the duplicate question=))

Comment: no more error message, but not saving changes on the book other variable on edit and not deleting as well