# Mongoid_slug Rails 4 update / destroy object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, slug

I am using mongoig_slug gem in my rails app.

I can create an object with the proper url but I can't update / delete the object and I have no error message in the console. (I can edit the form, which contains the correct data)

I even used PRY to check in the console and when I check @book exits and is correct, if I do @book.destroy it says true but does not destroy. 
For the edit, I also checked @book, I also checked book_params which is correct.

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Slug

  field :_id, type: String, slug_id_strategy: lambda {|id| id.start_with?('....')}

  field :name, type: String
  slug :name 
end

class BooksController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :get_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   def update
     if @book.update_attributes(book_params)
       redirect_to book_path(@book)
     else
       flash.now[:error] = "The profile was not saved, please try again."
       render :edit
     end
   end

   def destroy
     binding.pry
     @book.destroy
     redirect_to :back
   end

   def book_params
     params.require(:book).permit(:name)
   end

   def get_book
     @book = Book.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

Comment: It's `@startup.destroy`, not `@book.destroy`, so you don't destroy the book.

Comment: It was just a typo as I was on 2 different projects but my code is @book.destroy

Comment: I updated the answer, hope it helps. [This example](https://github.com/zishe/mongoslug-example) work correctly for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just copy that line `slug_id_strategy: lambda {|id| id.start_with?('....')}` without changes. You should replace dots with something that defines is it id or not.

From docs:

> This option should return something that responds to call (a callable) and takes one string argument, e.g. a lambda. This callable must return true if the string looks like one of your ids.

So, it could be, for example:

```
slug_id_strategy: lambda { |id| id.start_with?('5000') } # ids quite long and start from the same digits for mongo.
```

or:

```
slug_id_strategy: lambda { |id| =~ /^[A-z\d]+$/ }
```

or probably:

```
slug_id_strategy: -> (id) { id =~ /^[[:alnum:]]+$/ }
```

**Updated**

The latest version of `mongoid_slug` is outdated, you should use github version. So in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mongoid_slug', github: 'digitalplaywright/mongoid-slug'
```

Also change `field: _id` line to:

```
  field :_id, type: BSON::ObjectId, slug_id_strategy: lambda { |id| id =~ /^[[:alnum:]]+$/ }
```

Cause `_id` type is not a string, and this occurs error. This should work.

Comment: Thank you. Is it mandatory to have this line slug_id_strategy: lambda...,  and therefore I guess i would need to check the name variable first to make sure of the format ?

Comment: No, it's additional code, for finding object by id, not by name. You can use the same `find` as i understand.

Comment: It gives me an error message: syntax error, unexpected '='
...d_strategy: lambda { |id| id ~= \^[A-z\d]+$\ }   for slug_id_strategy: lambda { |id| id ~= \^[A-z\d]+$\ }

Comment: I am really sorry but I don't understand

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake, i updated the post it should be `=~` and slashes in wrong side=) Just checked it should work.

Comment: By the way, there is a daw near the answer, you should accept it, if it solved a problem. I see you didn't accept any of 10, you probably don't know about it. Check the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55790/discussion-between-chleo-and-zishe).